# How can I deploy 3rd party go libraries to Bluemix Hyperledger?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I would like to deploy 3rd party libraries to help with the logic in my chaincode. How can I deploy these libraries to Hyperledger on Bluemix?  I have successfully deployed chaincode without libraries, but now would like to try with libraries. However, the examples I've seen only point to a github directory with the chaincode go file and nothing else.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect vendoring all the dependencies would work well. It has for me in the past.